# Dll reference is not working.

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I have created one .dll name CSSupport2010 for different functionalities with C# code.When I am adding it to another project(Windows Application) as a reference it is allowing it to do so and when I am writing the namespace of the .dll in the .cs file it is showing in the intellisense.But the problem is when i am building the project it is showing error that "The type or namespace name "CSSuport2010" could not be found ".Can any one please help me out with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If there isn't a typo in this - "The type or namespace name "CSSuport2010" could not be found " then the problem is that CSSuport2010 is missing a p, it should be CSSupport2010.

Otherwise, here are a few things to check when you have this problem; 1) Check the dll's properties, make sure the reference path is correct and if you want it in the bin make sure copy-local is set to 'if newer' or 'always'. 2) Make sure the dll is up to date. 3) Make sure you have the proper `using` statements in all the files which use `CSSupport2010`.

Comment: Thanks a lot **evanmcdonnal** for your reply.I have tried as you said but still the problem persists.I am not getting any clue.If you have any clue,then please let me know. Thanks in advance